# how can I use Stripejs in vue 3?

Tags: stripe-payments, vuejs3

I'm working on a project with Nestjs backend and Vue 3 in the front end. But I could not find a way to use [Vue Stripe](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@vue-stripe/vue-stripe) with Vuejs3.
any help, please?

Comment: This seems to be pretty specific to Vue Stripe, so I'd suggest you reach out to them / on their repo instead.

Comment: that's what i just did, thank you